# How do I implement hashids in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hashids

I will go ahead and apologize upfront as I am new to ruby and rails and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement using hashids in my project. The project is a simple image host. I have it already working using Base58 to encode the sql ID and then decode it in the controller. However I wanted to make the URLs more random hence switching to hashids.

I have placed the hashids.rb file in my lib directory from here: https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb

Now some of the confusion starts here. Do I need to initialize hashids on every page that uses hashids.encode and hashids.decode via

```
hashids = Hashids.new("mysalt")
```

I found this post (http://zogovic.com/post/75234760043/youtube-like-ids-for-your-activerecord-models) which leads me to believe I can put it into an initializer however after doing that I am still getting NameError (undefined local variable or method `hashids' for ImageManager:Class)

so in my ImageManager.rb class I have

```
require 'hashids'

class ImageManager
class << self
def save_image(imgpath, name)

  mime = %x(/usr/bin/exiftool -MIMEType #{imgpath})[34..-1].rstrip
  if mime.nil? || !VALID_MIME.include?(mime)
    return { status: 'failure', message: "#{name} uses an invalid format." }
  end

  hash = Digest::MD5.file(imgpath).hexdigest
  image = Image.find_by_imghash(hash)

  if image.nil?
    image = Image.new
    image.mimetype = mime
    image.imghash = hash
    unless image.save!
      return { status: 'failure', message: "Failed to save #{name}." }
    end

    unless File.directory?(Rails.root.join('uploads'))
      Dir.mkdir(Rails.root.join('uploads'))
    end
    #File.open(Rails.root.join('uploads', "#{Base58.encode(image.id)}.png"), 'wb') { |f| f.write(File.open(imgpath, 'rb').read) }
    File.open(Rails.root.join('uploads', "#{hashids.encode(image.id)}.png"), 'wb') { |f| f.write(File.open(imgpath, 'rb').read) }
  end

  link = ImageLink.new
  link.image = image
  link.save

#return { status: 'success', message: Base58.encode(link.id) }
return { status: 'success', message: hashids.encode(link.id) }
end

private

    VALID_MIME = %w(image/png image/jpeg image/gif)
  end
end
```

And in my controller I have:

```
require 'hashids'

class MainController < ApplicationController
MAX_FILE_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024
MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 128 * 1024 * 1024

@links = Hash.new
@files = Hash.new
@tstamps = Hash.new
@sizes = Hash.new
@cache_size = 0

class << self
  attr_accessor :links
  attr_accessor :files
  attr_accessor :tstamps
  attr_accessor :sizes
  attr_accessor :cache_size
  attr_accessor :hashids
end

def index
end

def transparency
end

def image
  #@imglist = params[:id].split(',').map{ |id| ImageLink.find(Base58.decode(id)) }
  @imglist = params[:id].split(',').map{ |id| ImageLink.find(hashids.decode(id)) }
end

def image_direct
  #linkid = Base58.decode(params[:id])
  linkid = hashids.decode(params[:id])

  file =
    if Rails.env.production?
      puts "#{Base58.encode(ImageLink.find(linkid).image.id)}.png"
      File.open(Rails.root.join('uploads', "#{Base58.encode(ImageLink.find(linkid).image.id)}.png"), 'rb') { |f| f.read }
    else
      puts "#{hashids.encode(ImageLink.find(linkid).image.id)}.png"
      File.open(Rails.root.join('uploads', "#{hashids.encode(ImageLink.find(linkid).image.id)}.png"), 'rb') { |f| f.read }
    end

  send_data(file, type: ImageLink.find(linkid).image.mimetype, disposition: 'inline')
end

def upload
  imgparam = params[:image]

  if imgparam.is_a?(String)
    name = File.basename(imgparam)
    imgpath = save_to_tempfile(imgparam).path
  else
    name = imgparam.original_filename
    imgpath = imgparam.tempfile.path
  end

  File.chmod(0666, imgpath)
  %x(/usr/bin/exiftool -all= -overwrite_original #{imgpath})
  logger.debug %x(which exiftool)
  render json: ImageManager.save_image(imgpath, name)
end

private

  def save_to_tempfile(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = uri.scheme == 'https'
  http.start do
    resp = http.get(uri.path)
    file = Tempfile.new('urlupload', Dir.tmpdir, :encoding => 'ascii-8bit')
    file.write(resp.body)
    file.flush
    return file
  end
end
end
```

Then in my image.html.erb view I have this:

```
<%
   @imglist.each_with_index { |link, i|
   id = hashids.encode(link.id)
   ext = link.image.mimetype.split('/')[1]
   if ext == 'jpeg'
     ext = 'jpg'
   end
   puts id + '.' + ext
%>
```

Now if I add

```
hashids = Hashids.new("mysalt")
```

in ImageManager.rb main_controller.rb and in my image.html.erb I am getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x000000062f69c0>)
```

So all in all implementing hashids.encode/decode is not as easy as implementing Base58.encode/decode and I am confused on how to get it working... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest loading it as a gem by including it into your `Gemfile` and running `bundle install`. It will save you the hassle of requiring it in every file and allow you to manage updates using Bundler.

Yes, you do need to initialize it wherever it is going to be used with the same salt. Would suggest that you define the salt as a constant, perhaps in `application.rb`.

The link you provided injects `hashids` into ActiveRecord, which means it will not work anywhere else. I would not recommend the same approach as it will require a high level of familiarity with Rails.

You might want to spend some time understanding ActiveRecord and ActiveModel. Will save you a lot of reinventing the wheel. :)

Comment: Even when I initialize the hashids method in each of the files it's still causing problems which I can't figure out. When using the Base58 class I could just encode and decode in the controller without issues. When using hashids.decode it doesn't appear to work the same which is giving me the "undefined method 'id' error". 

It looks like it's not decoding it... How do I properly decode the id in the controller?

I do plan to go back and do the tutorials on railstutorials.org and get a better understanding of ruby on rails once this id issue is fixed.

Comment: @mroth7684: You're missing a closing curly brace in `image.html.erb`. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, it's further down on the page. I finally got it working. The issue was hashids returns an array instead of just the integer. I just needed to adjust the code to use the array after decoding.

Comment: @mroth7684: can you add the solution you found that solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Before everythink you should just to test if  Hashlib is included in your project, you can run command `rails c` in your project folder and make just a small test :

```
>> my_id = ImageLink.last.id
>> puts Hashids.new(my_id)
```

If not working, add the gem in gemfile (that anyway make a lot more sence).

---

Then, I think you should add a getter for your hash_id in your ImageLink model.
Even you don't want to save your hash in the database, this hash have it's pllace in your model. See virtual property for more info.

Remember "Skinny Controller, Fat Model".

```
class ImageLink < ActiveRecord::Base 

    def hash_id()
        # cache the hash
        @hash_id ||= Hashids.new(id)
    end

    def extension()
        # you could add the logic of extension here also.
        ext = image.mimetype.split('/')[1]
        if ext == 'jpeg'
           'jpg'
        else
            ext
        end
    end
end
```

Change the return in your ImageManager#save_image

```
link = ImageLink.new
link.image = image
# Be sure your image have been saved (validation errors, etc.)
if link.save 
    { status: 'success', message: link.hash_id }
else
    {status: 'failure', message: link.errors.join(", ")}
end
```

In your template

```
<%
   @imglist.each_with_index do |link, i|
    puts link.hash_id + '.' + link.extension
   end # <- I prefer the do..end to not forgot the ending parenthesis
%>
```

All this code is not tested...

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar where I can disguise the ids of my records. I came across *act_as_hashids*.

https://github.com/dtaniwaki/acts_as_hashids

This little gem integrates seamlessly. You can still find your records through the ids. Or with the hash. On nested records you can use the method `with_hashids`.

To get the hash you use `to_param` on the object itself which result in a string similar to this `ePQgabdg`.

Since I just implemented this I can't tell how useful this gem will be. So far I just had to adjust my code a little bit.

I also gave the records a virtual attribute hashid so I can access it easily.

```
attr_accessor :hashid
after_find :set_hashid

private
    def set_hashid
        self.hashid = self.to_param
    end
```